# ¿Cómo podria alterar el tamaño de un canvas pero sin que me cambie la posición al dibujar en él?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Estoy tratando de hacer una especie de paint en javascript con diferentes funcionalidades, tales como, cambiar el color, el grosor, tener un borrador, limpiar el canvas, y descargar la imagen, que funcionan perfectamente, pero cuando le hago zoom a la pantalla desde el navegador no dibuja desde donde yo pongo el mouse sino desde otra posición. He tratado de ponerle un tamaño fijo pero no sirve de nada, así que el tamaño se lo estoy especificando directamente desde el HTML. En CSS lo único que hice fue poner borde al canvas y cambiarle el diseño al link de descargar para que este parezca un botón, también creé dos variables llamadas caux y gaux donde se guardan el color y el grosor pero no se modifican al presionar el botón de borrador, para que cuando se presione lápiz, vuelva a estar como antes de haber pulsado borrador. Además el botón de descargar si sirve pero no aquí en stackoverflow sino cuando lo inicio directamente. Este es el código:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var x=0, y=0, dibujando=false, color="black", grosor="1",caux="black",gaux="1";

function defcolor(c){
    color = c;
    caux = c;
}

function defgrosor(g){
    grosor = g;
    gaux = g;
}

function pincel(p){
    color = caux;
    grosor = gaux;
}

function borrar(b){
    color = "white";
    grosor = "20"
}

function limpiar(l){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

descargar = function(d) {
    var imageURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
    d.href = imageURI;
  }

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){
    x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    dibujando = true;
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
    if (dibujando===true){ 
        dibujar(x,y,e.clientX - rect.left,e.clientY - rect.top);
        x = e.clientX - rect.left;
        y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e){
    if (dibujando===true){
        dibujar(x,y,e.clientX - rect.left,e.clientY - rect.top);
        x=0;
        y=0;
        dibujando = false;
    }
});

function dibujar(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = grosor;
    ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2,y2)
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
#canvas{
    border:1px solid black;
}

#descargar {
    font: bold 11px Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Paint</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas> <br>
    <input type="color" id="color" oninput="defcolor(this.value);">
    <input type="range" id="grosor" oninput="defgrosor(this.value);" min="1" max="10" value="1">
    <input type="button" id="pincel" onclick="pincel();" value="Pincel">
    <input type="button" id="borrador" onclick="borrar();" value="Borrador">
    <input type="button" id="limpiar" onclick="limpiar()" value="Limpiar">
    <a id="descargar" download="imagen.jpg" href="" onclick="descargar(this);">Descargar</a>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poner un tamaño fijo al canvas es inutil si lo que intentas es mediante la lupa del navegador, pues esta lo unico que hace escalar todo el contenido en partes iguales de la pagina web, en pocas palabras, hagas lo que hagas no podras afectar el efecto de la lupa, pues este es omnipotente y omnipresente :v

Comment: Es mas que todo un efecto que obtienes por escalar el canvas mediante la lupa, pues el dibujado del canvas se adaptara al tamano del canvas en la pantalla pero las propiedades del canvas en si no deberian, por ejemplo, puede que al escalar el canvas con zoom el siguiente trazado que hagas sea mucho mas delgado que el canvas sin escalar, las coordenadas equivaldrian entonces ahora a .10, .20 o .50, etc mas que el tamaño origen.

Comment: De todas maneras te tengo una pregunta muy basica, y es,  en que te afecta que tu le hagas zoom al canvas si la imagen descargada tendra la resolucion real de tu canvas?, es decir, que tu le hagas zoom a la imagen no significa que el resultado descargado vaya a variar, el canvas mantendra su resolucion original como output, por lo tanto mantendra sus coordenadas originales y tamaño a la hora de descargarlo. cual seria entonces la pregunta realmente?, cual es el problema de esto?, porque usar el zoom del navegador te genera un inconveniente o le afecta al canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que no haya entendido tu pregunta. Lo que tu dices que no dibuja donde pones el ratón pasa al hacer scroll no zoom.

Si esto es lo que querías decir a continuación viene el código.

Principalmente he añadido una función para detectar la posición del ratón en el canvas. La función toma como argumento el elemento canvas utilizado y el evento evt

```
function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
}
}
```

En tu código detectas la caja delimitadora del canvas `canvas.getBoundingClientRect()` una sola vez al inicio. Después haces scroll y el canvas cambia de posición. Por esto que tienes que detectar la caja delimitadora durante los eventos. Y para no repetir el código mejor ponerlo todo en una función.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

let m = {};

var x=0, y=0, dibujando=false, color="black", grosor="1",caux="black",gaux="1";

function defcolor(c){
    color = c;
    caux = c;
}

function defgrosor(g){
    grosor = g;
    gaux = g;
}

function pincel(p){
    color = caux;
    grosor = gaux;
}

function borrar(b){
    color = "white";
    grosor = "20"
}

function limpiar(l){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

descargar = function(d) {
    var imageURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
    d.href = imageURI;
  }

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){
    m = oMousePos(canvas, e)
    x = m.x;
    y = m.y;
    dibujando = true;
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
    if (dibujando===true){ 
        m = oMousePos(canvas, e);
        dibujar(x,y,m.x,m.y);
        x = m.x;
        y = m.y;
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e){
    if (dibujando===true){
        m= oMousePos(canvas, e)
        dibujar(x,y,m.x,m.y);
        x=0;
        y=0;
        dibujando = false;
    }
});

function dibujar(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = grosor;
    ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2,y2)
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
}
}
```

```css
#canvas{
    border:1px solid black;
}

#descargar {
    font: bold 11px Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas> <br>
    <input type="color" id="color" oninput="defcolor(this.value);">
    <input type="range" id="grosor" oninput="defgrosor(this.value);" min="1" max="10" value="1">
    <input type="button" id="pincel" onclick="pincel();" value="Pincel">
    <input type="button" id="borrador" onclick="borrar();" value="Borrador">
    <input type="button" id="limpiar" onclick="limpiar()" value="Limpiar">
    <a id="descargar" download="imagen.jpg" href="" onclick="descargar(this);">Descargar</a>
```

Este es un articulo que explica como [detectar la posición del ratón en el canvas](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/canvas/mouse-position.php)

Comment: Dibuje un cubito :3